# c++14 value initialization issue

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

Who knows wy local i_local value is zero-initialized in this example http://ideone.com/Cqer9Z?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    int i_local; // automatic storage duration, not static

    cout << "Value of i_local: " << i_local << endl; // (2-3) value is undetermined
}
```

It is variable with automatic storage duration and according to standart is should have undetermined value.

In my local computer (c++11) it is undetermined but in ideone (c++14) zeroed.

Comment: but isn't that implementation specific? I don't recall the standard specifying that this should be unintialised or initialised for local variables

Comment: as c++14 says -  If no initializer is specified for an object, the object is default-initialized; if no initialization is performed, an
object with automatic or dynamic storage duration has indeterminate value. [ Note: Objects with static or
thread storage duration are zero-initialized, see 3.6.2. — end note ]

Comment: Why have you determined that an undetermined value shouldn't be zero?

Comment: This is strange because I_local is allocated in stack and it's value should be garbage (what i have in my computer). But here it is 0.

Comment: If only stack is not zeroed before programm execution starts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In full, the standard says (emphasis added):

> When storage for an object with automatic or dynamic storage duration is obtained, the object has an indeterminate value, and if no initialization is performed for the object, that object retains an indeterminate value until that value is replaced (5.18). [...] **If an indeterminate value is produced by an evaluation, the behavior is undefined** except [in some irrelevant cases...]

You have undefined behaviour. It could print 0, it could print 50, it could print gibberish, or it could wipe your hard drive.

Comment: so this is just a coincidence that value is 0?

Comment: It couldn't wipe your hard drive. Explaining UB is important but let's not get carried away with alternate universe theories!

Comment: @LightningRacisinObrit I am a C++ implementation and if I see this in your code, I come to your house and wipe your hard drives. All of them.

Comment: @LightningRacisinObrit so the urban legend about the [nasal demons](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=nasal+demons) is also a lie? :O Just joking, I completely agree there's a limit to the behaviour of *undefined behaviour*, at least it should be defined on the compiler side, isn't it?

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster Nope, that would be Implementation-Defined Behaviour  (which is different than Unspecified Behaviour, which is different than Undefined Behaviour).

Comment: @AndreKostur I meant that when standard says *undefined behaviour* the compilers should define *something* to place in this *gap* (even if they place nothing in there, but to put nothing is something deliberate after all), so is *undefined* from the standard point of view and *sort of defined* from the point of view of the compiler.

Comment: At the _very_ least, the set of possible symptoms of UB is limited by the physical constraints of the universe. If your computer can open a black hole I'd love to see it! (Or maybe not...)

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster defined means "some thought was put into what would happen, and some guarantees are made".  Under the C++ standard, no thought need be put into it, and no guarantees need be made.  C++ compilers have, in practice, used the fact that your code will (in the future) generate UB if a certain thing is true, and optimized the code in such a way that **earlier** statements behave differently if that statement was true.  In short, if you have `if (x && (ptr!=nullptr)) { do some stuff that cannot change *ptr, or exit }; *ptr = 3;` the compiler can *strip the `ptr!=nullptr` test*.

Comment: Now, that is seemingly sane, but the same is true of `if (x >= 0) { /* code that cannot change x or exit the function */ } x = (int)(unsigned)x;` -- the compiler is free to strip the `x >= 0` test as if `x<0` then `(int)(unsigned)x` executes undefined behavior, so the compiler can *prove* that `x>=0` retroactively.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit  It really can wipe your hard drive (sometimes): https://kristerw.blogspot.com/2017/09/why-undefined-behavior-may-call-never.html  It you pair that with the time travel example it even gets worse: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140627-00/?p=633

Comment: @JerryJeremiah: Sorry, missed your comment - had computer trouble. It seems my hard drive died a few years ago and somehow I hadn't noticed until this morning

Answer (score 2):

Zero is one of the values of `int`, therefore it's perfectly legal for an `int` of undetermined value to be zero.

Furthermore, it's UB to even attempt to read that integer, so the value you see is by definition meaningless.